# how to see the value in a tensor object

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a variable `a` it has the output `a = Tensor("Mean_32:0"`, `shape=(), dtype=float64)`

how can I see the value present in the form of tensor

```
a = Tensor("Mean_32:0", shape=(), dtype=float64)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `tf.Session()` context to evaluate the tensors.

Example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = tf.constant([1., 2., 3.])
mean = tf.reduce_mean(tensor)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  # both are equivalent:
  print(mean.eval()) # 2.0
  print(sess.run(mean)) # 2.0
```